# What is the $\angle EBF$?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

[image]

> $ABCD$ is a square. If $\angle EFB= \angle BFC$ what is $\angle EBF?$

I can only think of the Z-rule and say that $\angle BFC = \angle FBA$. After that I can't progress any further.

I think the problem might be missing some details and that it has infinitely many solutions, but moving the points $E$ and $F$ on the square (in GeoGebra) while maintaining the angle bisector, I only get $\angle EBF $ to be ~$45^o$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: With the information you have given us, if could be anything. (Well, not _anything_, but there is a large range of possible angles.) You can freely move the point $F$ along $CD$, and then take whatever angle $\angle BFC$ is, and duplicate it to make $\angle BFE$, which will then tell you where $E$ lands. As long as $E$ lands on $AD$, you're good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be the point on $EF$ such that $BK\perp EF$. Then $\triangle BCF\cong \triangle BKF$. This implies that $BK=BC=BA$ and hence $\triangle ABE\cong \triangle KBE$.

$\angle ABE=\angle KBE$ and $\angle CBF=\angle KBF$.

$\angle EBF=\angle ABC\div 2=45^\circ$.